# What were the cultural attitudes of Indian proto-scientists to findings versus recognition; and knowledge as private property; between 1526 and 1949?

Tags: scientific-method, india

[Elsewhere](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/613/does-anyone-know-about-ramanujans-method-of-solving-the-quartic) it has been suggested that, between 1526 and 1949, that Indian proto-scientists "were more interested in sharing knowledge with the rest of the world," than in knowledge as private property, and that they "were more interested in the findings than obtaining recognition."

What were the cultural expectations in Indian proto-sciences regarding knowledge as property, recognition, and findings?

Comment: If someone with appropriate rep could tag the currently non-existing tags: India, proto-science and intellectual-property it would be appreciated.

Comment: I created the tags, though it's up to the community as to whether or not they're good.

Comment: I think the term proto-scientist is ill-defined, and perhaps 'india' should be replaced by something more localized in time.